# How can I remove the randomness of a decision tree on sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, deterministic

I'm trying to create a deterministic decision tree in python, but I've some issue.

If I run 2 times my script I get to different Decision Trees, because of the random_state of the algorithm.

I tried to fixed random_state( `random_state=0`) but It's still not working.

I'd like to remove the randomness of my decision tree but I can t find a clear solution.

Comment: You should check for more randomness in your code, like train_test_split that could be influencing the tree.

Comment: Can you `random.seed` the generator?

Comment: Thanks for yours responses,
- I checked in my code but the split between the train test split is fixed.
- what do you mean by random.seed the generator ?

Comment: Thank you, it works now

Comment: Note: Deleted my comment to make an official answer

Answer (score 3):

Sklearn uses the random seed from numpy, so you can set the global seed at the start of your script with:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

**The `random_state` argument should work but here are 2 different options**

**Option 1:**

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000, criterion='mse', min_samples_leaf=4, 
                           random_state= 0)
```

**This should return the same results every single time.**

---

> Scikit-learn does not use its own global random state; whenever a
>   RandomState instance or an integer random seed is not provided as an
>   argument, it relies on the numpy global random state, which can be set
>   using numpy.random.seed

---

**Option 2:**

That being said, **adding** `np.random.seed()` **before** **importing** the `RandomForestRegressor` **should also do the trick.**

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
```

Source: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-set-a-random-state-for-an-entire-execution